# How to suppress numbers in Bash history?

Tags: bash, history

i been reading one of tutorial there but it does not work, [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110119/bash-history-without-line-numbers)

I got something like this in my bash_history file

```
#1314423157
mc
#1314423160
top
#1314423240
exit
```

ect...

how to remove numbers from being stored in my history file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man bash
```

I have emphasized the key phrase here

HISTTIMEFORMAT

If  this  variable  is  set and not null, its value is used as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated with  each  history  entry displayed by the history builtin.  **If this variable is set, time stamps are  written  to  the  history file** so they may be preserved across shell sessions.

Comment: Accually i got it defined somewhere else or perheaps it is defined in history itself. Neither bashrc or profile got any option for HISTTIMEFORMAT, anyway i just did HISTTIMEFORMAT=0 in profile and it went away. Thanks for pointing to me it was timestamp :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bash variable `HISTTIMEFORMAT`: if it is set, the timestamp will be saved with the history entry. If you unset this variable (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`), the timestamp should disappear entirely.