# how do strip column from grep in terminal

Tags: linux, grep

when I run the command
`history | grep "apt-get install"`
it returns the below text

```
 243  sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
  280  sudo apt-get install weavedconnectd
  329  sudo apt-get install foremost
  336  sudo apt-get install nbtstat -y
  357  sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
  372  sudo apt-get install debian-zfs
  373  sudo apt-get install raspbian-zfs
  374  sudo apt-get install zfs
  434  sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs -y
  447  sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
  703  sudo apt-get install xrdp
  733  sudo apt-get install tightvncserver 
 1126  sudo apt-get install lcdproc
 1151  sudo apt-get install webalizer
 1152  sudo apt-get install webalizer -yf
 1213  sudo apt-get install python-pip
 1214  sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

while I just want from sudo uphill the package name. i.e strip of the number. so that in future if I have to install these packages I can just directly copy paste the text from a saved file to shell.

Comment: See: [Bash history without line numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7110119/3776858)

Comment: `history | grep 'apt-get install' | cut -d' ' -f5-`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of sed and cut to strip whitespace and pick out the fields that you want.

`history | grep "apt-get install" | sed 's/^ *//' | cut -d' ' -f3-`

The sed command will pull out the leading whitespace from the history output and cut will split the output into columns allowing you to choose only the commands.

Comment: but I am trying to exclude the old greps of history using --exclude flag but doesnt seem to work , can you update in your answer ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but perhaps an inverted match to filter out your grep commands? e.g. `grep -v "^grep"` I think the top level comment is also a good solution.

Comment: I want to exclude all the previous grep searches in the result using -v flag it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output to sed and strip the unwanted part, like this:

```
history | grep "apt-get install" | sed 's/^\s*[[:digit:]]\+\s*//'
```

The sed regex will match:

`^`: at the beginning of each line
`\s*`: any amount of space characters, followed by
`[[:digit:]]\+`: one or more digits, followed by
`\s*` any amount of spaces (eager)